# Error Persisting Entity List - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager

Tags: jpa, transactions, illegalstateexception

I would like to persist a List of Entities using JPA with Spring MVC but received the following error.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead

I tried googling for an answer but couldn't apply the solutions to my situation.

Here's the method from my Service Implementation.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveTemporaryRecords(List<TemporaryRecord> temporaryRecords) {

    for (TemporaryRecord temporaryRecord : temporaryRecords) {

        try {
            temporaryRecordDao.persist(temporaryRecord);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The temporaryRecordDao interface and its implementation don't have any methods, they extend AbstractDao implementation with the following method:

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

@Override
public void persist(Entity entity) throws Exception {

    if (entity == null) {
        throw new Exception("Entity is null");
    }

    try {
        em.persist(entity);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        em.close();
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml has the following related configuration:

```
<!-- Configure Entity Manager -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
            p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
            p:packagesToScan="hu.beczdev.webbudgetapp.model">

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
            p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" p:showSql="true" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure TransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The saveTemporaryRecords method was called inside another method, which was reading data from database (and had no @Transactional annotation). This messed up the transactions. I removed the @Transactional annotation from saveTemporaryRecords and put it on the caller method and it solved the problem.